# RxJava / RxKotlin - andThen still executing if previous step fails. How to stop?

Tags: kotlin, rx-java2, rx-kotlin2

I'm new to RxJava and am having a hard time with handling error cases. The application is in Kotlin but it probably won't make much of a difference. The scenario is basically user authentication and then performing an action but if the user is not authorized/has a bad auth token I generate an exception and want to cease processing. Right now I have my function that checks tokens and it looks like this.

```
fun checkAuthority(authToken: AuthToken, requiredAuthority: Authority): Completable =
    authorityRepository.getAuthorities(authToken)
        .filter { it == requiredAuthority }
        .switchIfEmpty { subscriber -> subscriber.onError(UnauthorizedException("must have '$requiredAuthority' authority")) }
        .ignoreElements()
```

Then I have a function that looks a bit like this that checks permissions then is supposed to do an operation if they are authorized.

```
fun create(model: EntityCreate, authToken: AuthToken): Single<Entity> =
    checkAuthority(authToken, CAN_WRITE_ENTITY)
        .andThen(entityRepository.insert(model, OffsetDateTime.now(clock)))
```

What I want is that if the UnauthorizedException is generated to not execute the andThen.

Perhaps there is a gap in my understanding of the documentation but I've for instance tried putting `doOnError` to throw the Throwable before the `andThen`. I've tried `onErrorComplete` in the same place. No matter what I do the `andThen` eventually executes.

What would the pattern look like to abandon the `Completable` chain should the `subscriber.onError` line executes?

Comment: That `switchIfEmpty` parameter is wrong, you should not create a reactive source that way. Use `switchIfEmpty(Observable.error(UnauthorizedException("...")))` instead at least. If you write `entityRepository.insert(model, OffsetDateTime.now(clock))` on its own, does it execute immediately or is it waiting for a subscription? If the former, wrap the entire call into `X.defer { entityRepository.insert(model, OffsetDateTime.now(clock)) }` of the appropriate reactive type X.

Comment: Wrapping the insert with Single.defer seemed to work as far as my tests go. Changing the switchIfEmpty as you described complained that it should be a Publisher and not an Observable. Could you perhaps write an answer and explain why defer worked here a little? I'd obviously accept it. Reading the javadoc on the defer function still leaves me a little confused as to why it accomplished my goal. "Calls a Callable for each individual SingleObserver to return the actual Single source to be subscribed to." is what the javadoc for Single.defer.

Comment: The types are not apparent in your code. Use Flowable.error then. Where does that entityRepository come from, what library?

Comment: The entityRepository in the case of an insert returns a Single<Entity>. It's just an interface backed by a class storing data in a hashmap. This is a bit of a dummy app but I was going to back it with a proper data layer soon. The authorities are returned as a Flowable from a similar setup.